# How to use java mysql program on another computer

Tags: java, mysql, database

I wrote a program using Intellij IDEA and MySQL. I take data from SQL database and put it to Swing objects in my Java program. It works on my computer, where i wrote it, but when i test it on another one(now i actualy trying to run it on my computer by using VirtualBox with Windows 10 PRO on it) Java doesn't connect to SQL.
The main thing that it is not the same database i use on development PC, i gonna create the same database on another computer.
I connect to my database using this:

```
 public static String userName = "root";
 public static String password = "1234";
 public static String Url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tablename? 
 verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
 Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(Url,userName,password);
```

And it works as i want.But when i create the same database on target PC, where is no any IDE, just JRE and MySQL Server 8.0.12 it is not working.I've tried to change `mysql://localhost:3306/tablename` or `localhost:3306/tablename`but it is not working.
I mean i dont get any data to fields where it should be.And i also dont know how to use any kind of 'debug" in this case, because i run it as a program without IDE.
I get JAR file using 'build artifact'.

How can i make my programm run on another PC with another(mirrored) database on it?

Comment: when you mention *not working* what exactly you mean ?

Comment: `localhost` is - as the name implies - the _local_ computer, i.e. the one your application is running on (IP 127.0.0.1). You need to replace that with the IP of the target computer as a minimum. Then the target computer needs to listen on that port, it must be reachable via the network etc.

Comment: @Ravi thank for correcting. I've edited. I mean there is no data in fields it shoul be

Comment: @Bukas haven't you used logging ? that will help you to debug your program. Look for exception if any, and share it with us.

Comment: @Ravi Well i am a REAL NOOB in it so i never used logging, and that is actually a thing i had to learn before making programs like this:(

Comment: @Thomas Is "jdbc:mysql://" part OK for this case, or i should use only IP instead of localhost?

Comment: Then, it is impossible to answer your question except *shooting in the dark*

Comment: @Ravi Yes, seems like it is. Thank for trying to help me, and sorry for taking your time

Comment: Well `"jdbc:mysql://` would just mean the protocol which should be ok. Basically, assuming you didn't change anything else, your connection string would look like `"jdbc:mysql://<ip_of_the_computer>:3306/databasename?<params>"` (note that it's not "tablename").

Comment: @Thomas Okay, and another stupid question: "Which ip should i use? My local IP such as 192.168.1.38 or global like 163.172.127.30?

Comment: Well, that depends on your network configuration. If both computers are in the same network (e.g. at home) then the "local" ip should work. However, since you seem to have very little knowledge on that topic asking everything here on SO might be out of scope so I'd suggest grabbing a tutorial and trying a simple example first.

Comment: @Thomas thank you very much for your help. I will go to learn about it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has to be an exception thrown in your application but you don't know it happens. To see logs with stacktrace you can simply launch your jar using windows command prompt.

1. Open Windows Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`)
2. `cd` to the directory where you have your `jar` file.
3. Execute command: `java -jar yourJarFilename.jar`

When your application encounters any exception it will be printed in console. You can use it to investigate the problem.

Comment: Wow,it works,thanks))) It gives `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/smartooth?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC` exception

Comment: That's probably because your jar doesn't contain required library. Make sure you have `mysql-connector.jar` (or similar filename) on classpath and your build packs this library into your jar. If you liked this answer you can [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).